# We define a function $f : \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ by$ f([l])=[7l^2]$.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let $n$ be a natural number and let $k$ be an integer number. Let $[x]$ be the relation class of $x$  (integer number) modulo $n$.

How now to prove this is a function?

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ You have to prove that the map given by $[l] \mapsto [7l^2]$ is well defined, i.e. that it does not depend on the choice of a representative for $[l]$.

Comment: Is this correct?

 the domain X and codomain Y are given, so we only need to show that:

f is an relation from X to Y
f⊆X×Y

The domain of f is Z/nZ, every element in X is related to some element of Y ∀x∈Z/nZ,∃y∈Z/nZ:(x,y)∈f
No element of Z/nZ is related to more than one element of Z/nZ ∀x∈Z/nZ,∀y1,y2∈Z/nZ:(x,y1),(x,y2)∈f=>y1=y2

Answer (score 0):

To prove this is a function you need it to be well-defined.  That is, there are multiple choices of $l$ for $[l]$; you need to prove that regardless of this choice, the function $f$ will have the same result.  That is, you need to prove that if $[l_1]=[l_2]$, then $[7l_1^2]=[7l_2^2]$.